# Remove promise and make async

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make this function wait for the gunzip to finish. However the async version does not work. But the promise version works correct. What am I missing?

This works as expeacted

```
const unzipFile = (element) => {
  var csvName = element.slice(0, -3);
  console.log(appRoot + "\\" + csvName);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gunzip(appRoot + "\\" + element, appRoot + "\\csv\\" + csvName, () => {
      console.log("gunzip done!");
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

This does not work.

```
const unzipFile = async (element) => {
  var csvName = element.slice(0, -3);
  console.log(appRoot + "\\" + csvName);

    const result = await gunzip(appRoot + "\\" + element, appRoot + "\\csv\\" + csvName)
      console.log("gunzip done!", result);
      return result;
};
```

Comment: `await` awaits a promise, not a callback

Comment: Your question is off to a great start: it includes what you tried, what worked, what failed. The only piece missing is the exact package you are using for `gunzip` and its version. Depending on it, the library could "support promises if no callback is passed", or not.

Comment: Make a [promisified](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) version of `gunzip` so that you can await it as bambam mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated from the comments. gunzip-file does not support promises. However Promisify will fix the problem and make it possible to use async/await.

```
const util = require('util'); //Promisify
const gunzip = require("gunzip-file");

const promiseGunzip = util.promisify(gunzip);

const unzipFile = async (element) => {
  var csvName = element.slice(0, -3);
  console.log(appRoot + "\\" + csvName);
//Use promise version instead
  const result = await promiseGunzip(appRoot + "\\" + element, appRoot + "\\csv\\" + csvName)
  console.log("gunzip done!");
  return result;
};
```